# VBA http get request response is gibberish

Tags: vba, http, get

I tried to search for a quick answer to this but I did not see a response...so I apologize if this is redundant.

I am pretty new to VBA and only use it to pull data from APIs to make my life easier.

My question is about the response im getting from a particular API.  HEre is the code im using:

```
Dim URL As String: URL = "API URL HERE in json format"
Dim Http As New WinHttpRequest
Dim Resp As String
        Http.Open "GET", URL, False
        Http.Send
        Resp = Http.ResponseText

Debug.Print Resp
```

So the Resp text is complete gibberish...is this a security thing?  I pass a security key successfully when I use it in the browser so I assumed it was not that....  I have used this exact method on numerous APIs but this is the first time I have seen this garbled response.  FYI the url I am using works just fine in a browser.

The Resp looks like this for example:

gõi:?ñq¢²^2?7AÄ??æºz³Gs=Î Ü?¬«¤%?$ÖÉ'q¯¼|?¼²ôue¦½Þ"HË!ø5[4]s½?·Þ.OÛÃBh×?4"rÊÊ[r7

Thanks for any help!
Khauna